# Rmd notebook fails to show table with `difftime` column and zero rows

Tags: r, r-markdown, difftime

I've discovered that Rmd yields an error when you try to print table with zero rows and column with difftime class. Here's an example of Rmd file:
(I've inserted backslash in end of the chunks so it would be one code block, so delete them locally, please)

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
\```

```{r}
foo <- tibble(
    time_1 = as.Date("2020-04-28"),
    time_2 = as.Date("2020-04-27")
) %>%
    mutate(time_diff = time_1 - time_2)
\```

```{r}
foo
\```


```{r}
foo %>% slice(0)
# Error:
# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
# arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
\```
````

Do you know how to avoid that?
For now I've just converted it to numeric, but difftime is more convenient.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to print 0 rows with attributes

Comment: Well I don't know in advance how many rows would be in my real table. And in my case zero rows (when there are no time diffs between two parameters) is success. So that's why I'm printing it.